# OK, either I'm crazy or there is a bug in IBM's compiler

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'll buy anyone a beer if they can tell me why `streamstream<<(char)` ignores 0x05.
This program is producing `000102030406070809E280081150121314`

The expected output *I think* would have been something more like:
`00010203040506070809E2800811050505050505050550121314`

IBM i (a.k.a. AS/400) C++ compiler, running on V7R1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;


typedef int8_t byte;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    stringstream sstr2;
    sstr2 << char(0x00);
    sstr2 << char(0x01);
    sstr2 << char(0x02);
    sstr2 << char(0x03);
    sstr2 << char(0x04);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x06);
    sstr2 << char(0x07);
    sstr2 << char(0x08);
    sstr2 << char(0x09);
    sstr2 << char(0xe2);
    sstr2 << char(0x80);
    sstr2 << char(0x08);
    sstr2 << char(0x11);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x05);
    sstr2 << char(0x50);
    sstr2 << char(0x12);
    sstr2 << char(0x13);
    sstr2 << char(0x14);

    char c;
    sstr2 >> c;
    while (sstr2.good()) {
        cout << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (int)c;
        sstr2 >> c;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8071fa8977ae7231. Note that `stdint.h` is deprecated and that loop should be `while (sstr2 >> c)`.

Comment: I think <cstdint> is the preferred header, if necessary, when using c++.

Comment: I get `000102030405060708FFFFFFE2FFFFFF800811050505050505050550121314` running with [ideone in c++11 mode](http://ideone.com/mRWOOP)... Please add some details on your environment like what compiler etc.

Comment: Works in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Kelly Beard it can be so that this character is some control character (even casted to int) for a IBM terminal that you are using. Try output the stream in a text file and see the result.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow He's outputting to a stringstream, then converting to hex. No sending of binary codes to terminals here...

Comment: No.  I am simply asking streamstream to insert a 0x05 into it's stream and I ask cout to display it as TEXT, not a binary value to the terminal.

Comment: IBM i (a.k.a. AS/400) C++ compiler, running on V7R1.  This isn't a C++11-ready compiler.  The other comments like how I set up the while() loop or to use <cstdint> are bogus.  cstdint is a symbolic link to stdint.h

Comment: It does not work so well on other systems : g++ ignores the 09 if I believe chris, jpw and my own compiler :-(

Comment: I don't understand that.  Why should it ignore any value?

Comment: Here's the problem : `stringstream` is designed to hold **textually formatted** data - it's not designed to act as a container for an arbitrary byte stream. (use `std::vector` or just `std::string` for that). With GCC, 0x9 fails, because its a tab character and thus special. In your environment, it seems 0x5 is special for some reason. Not a bug, you're just misusing the `stringstream`,

Comment: Using [`noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) fixed it for me.

Comment: One needs to remember that iSeries is an EBCDIC machine.

Comment: ...and 0x05 is a horizontal tab in EBCDIC, just as 0x09 is a HT in ASCII.  So @Roddy, I owe you a drink.  :-)

Comment: @FredLarson, you too.  That worked for me.

Comment: Adding sstr2 << noskipws; before the first "<<" insert disabled any interpretation of the characters.  Doing that I was able to get "00010203040506070809E2800811050505050505050550121314" as my output.  Weird!

Comment: @KellyBeard:  `sstr2 >> anything` ignores leading whitespace by default.  That, alongside EBCDIC, is the key.  `noskipws` tells it not to skip whitespace.  Makes sense.

Comment: @Roddy: `stringstream` should be able to hold his data just fine, it's _totally_ an arbitrary byte stream.  What matters is if you use an formatted read, or an unformatted read.  `>>` is a formatted read, thus skipping whitespace.  `.read` or similar are unformatted reads, which behave as desired.

Comment: I confirm : I did some more test, and at `<<` all is fine, and size is incremented (including for tab (09 on Linux)), but on `>>` tab was skipped.

Comment: @MooingDuck. That makes sense. I wasn't sure if the `<<` formatted write was part of the problem. (And, do you require the std::stringstream::binary flag when the stream is constructed?)

Comment: @Roddy: er, yes.  Thanks for that correction.  It's an arbitrary byte stream when constructed with `std::stringstream::binary`.  My mistake on that oversight.

Comment: I have found that when deciding between compiler bug and me being crazy, crazy almost always wins out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's time to distil the hive-mind comment thread into something resembling a useful answer...

0x05 is giving you problems because your AS/400 uses EBCDIC encoding, and that's a tab character. On ASCII systems, character 0x09 (tab) gives a similar problem.

The `<<` and `>>` operators for `stringstream` are for *formatted* input and output, so whitespace characters (e.g. tabs, space - and line endings) can get altered.

You should use the option [`std::stringstream::binary`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) when you construct the stream, to prevent newline sequences getting changed.

Also, you have to tell the formatted read operator not to skip whitespace in the stream, using the [`noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) I/O manipulator.

Alternatively, you could just save your data to a generic container (e.g. std::vector, or std::string) and avoid this hassle entirely.

Comment: A quick experiment (with gcc on Linux) indicates that `sstr2 << "x\ty"` doesn't lose the tab character; it's only lost when you do `sstr >> ...`. You can still retrieve the raw contents of the stringstream using `sstr2.str()`. I haven't looked at what `binary` does; my guess is that it should only affect line endings (and should have no effect on UNIX-like systems).

Comment: Beer is due, I think.

Comment: @KeithThompson That would tally with my guesses too: But I'm not sure if that behaviour is guaranteed. Using `binary` seems a good belt-and-braces approach, especially as I have no idea about EBCDIC line termination sequences.